# Using Thread to Create Moving Ball Applet

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Eventually got the balls to move, but the app doesn't execute perfectly and I'm still unsure about the run() method setup... I don't think I need it but it's part of the assignment.  Please let me know if there's a better way.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BouncingBallApp extends JFrame
{
    //start of main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       //crate container
       Container container = new Container();
       //crate BouncingBallApp instance
       BouncingBallApp bBalls = new BouncingBallApp();
        //set the window closing feature(close with X click)
       bBalls.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       //crate boucing ball panel(BBP) instance and add
       BouncingBallPanel BBP = new BouncingBallPanel();
       container.add(BBP);
       //make the BBP the MouseListner
       bBalls.addMouseListener(BBP);
       //set window background and size
       bBalls.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       bBalls.setSize(400, 300);
       BBP.setSize(400, 300);
       BBP.setLayout(null);
       bBalls.setContentPane(BBP);
       //set window visible
       bBalls.setVisible(true);
    }//end of main method
}//end of Class BouncingBall App


class BouncingBallPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    //create an empty array for 20 Ball objects
    public Ball[] array; 
    private int count = 0;
    Random generator = new Random();

    public BouncingBallPanel()
    {
        array = new Ball[20];
    }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        array[count] = new Ball(this);
        count++;
        if( count == 1)
        {
            final Runnable update = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
                    {
                        if(array[j] != null)
                        {
                            array[j].move();
                        }//end of if
                    }//end of for 
                }//end of run method
            };//end of runnalbe update
            (new Thread(new Ball(this))).start();
            Runnable graphic = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            EventQueue.invokeLater(update);
                            Thread.sleep(generator.nextInt(10 +100));
                        }catch (InterruptedException exp){}
                    }//end of while
                }//end of run 
            };//end of runnable
            new Thread(graphic).start();
        }//end of if  
    }//end of mouseClicked method

    //empty interfaces for mouse events
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){}   

    //paint component method
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     //loop for each ball and draw all balls in array
     for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
        if(array[i] != null)
        {
         g2d.setColor(array[i].getColor());
         g2d.fillOval((int)array[i].getX(), (int)array[i].getY(), (int)array[i].getDiameter(), (int)array[i].getDiameter());
        }
     }//end of for loop
    }//end of paintComponent loop
}//end of Class BouncingBallPanel

class Ball implements Runnable
{
    //set up variables
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private int deltaX;
    private int deltaY;
    private double diameter;
    private Color color;
    BouncingBallPanel BBP2;

    Random random = new Random();

    public Ball(BouncingBallPanel a) 
    {
        x = random.nextInt(400);
        y = random.nextInt(300);
        deltaX = 1 + random.nextInt(10);
        deltaY = 1 + random.nextInt(10);
        diameter = 5 + random.nextInt(20);
        color = new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
        BBP2 = a;
    }// end of constructor

    public double getX() 
    {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
            return y;
    }

    public double getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void move() {
        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;

        if (x > 400 - getDiameter()|| x <0) 
        {
            deltaX = -deltaX;
        }

        if (y > 300 - getDiameter() || y < 0)
        {
            deltaY = -deltaY;
        }

    }// end of method move
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
         { 
            move();
            BBP2.repaint();       
            try{
               Thread.currentThread().sleep(10 + random.nextInt(100));
            }catch(InterruptedException exp){} 
           }//end of while 
    }//end of run method
}//end of Ball
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You never create threads for the balls. Just making an object `Runnable` does not implicitly create a thread. You need something like this in the constructor:

   `new Thread(this).start();`
2. In the Swing event model, using [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) is better than background threads. Using threads, you will see graphical artifacts if an object moves while the window is being painted.

Comment: +1. @user2520823 `setSize`, `setLayout(null);`, Im already cringing at the code. Use [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)! and override `getPreferredSize` of `JPanel` when and where necessary. Also I see no where `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block, this is needed or unexpected behaviour will occur intermittently (happens now and than hard to reproduce everytime) have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) Applies to applets and Swing though applets wuld use invokeAndWait in `init()`.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Actually, this is one of the cases where you need not wrap the GUI construction in an `invokeLater` - no code is run in the main thread after the first component is made displayable. But agreed that it's a bad practice regardless.

Comment: *no code is run in the main thread* as far as I see all code in `main(String[] args)` is run on the initial/main thread, and as far as I know any method called or modification done on a Swing component/object (unless specified thread safe like `repaint`) should be wrapped in a `invokeXXX` block (check the link Concurrency in swing in my previous comment) as to ensure it is run on the `Event Dispatch Thread` and not any other thread. As I have said there maybe no errors/artefacts now but unexpected behaviour can/will occur on other systems and perhaps as the code gets more lengthy

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: See [this article](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jtbauer/cis3931/tutorial/ui/swing/threads.html).

Comment: I cannot say I fully agree, especially when I read *Immediately afterward, the components in the GUI are shown with the setVisible (or show) call. Technically, the **setVisible call is unsafe because the components have already been realized by the pack call**. However, because the program doesn't already have a visible GUI, **it's exceedingly unlikely that a paint call will occur before setVisible returns.*** but i do see what you mean. lol technicalities lets leave it there.